# Called a decorator's returned value -- Python

Tags: python

I came across a problem for python decorator.

The question is:
Create a decorator which is responsible for multiplication of 2 numbers (say a,b), this multiplication of the numbers gives another number(say c).

Then needed to a create a actual function which does the summation of a,b and c.
Something like:

Decorator : a*b => c

Actual function: a+b+c

I have reached until this stage:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def addition(a,b):
        c = a*b
        return c
    return addition

@my_decorator
def actual_func(a,b):
    return a+b+c
```

But it gives error all the time.

Comment: The explanation you give doesn't explain how the decorator and the decorated function are supposed to fit together. Is the decorator's return value supposed to call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual func

- Takes a, b and multiplies them
- decorator sums original numbers plus ouput of multiply func

**Code**

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def addition(a,b):
        c = func(a, b)               # use multiplication function
        return a + b + c             # performs desired calculation
    return addition                  # modified function for desired calculation

@my_decorator
def actual_func(a,b):
    return a*b      # does multiplication

actual_func(2, 4)   # return 14 i.e. 2 + 4 + 2*4
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include your error in the question.

Your current state looks promising but there are small mistakes:

- the inner function (`addition`) should call `func` with the correct arguments (`a,b,c`) and return its return value
- `actual_func` should add the three numbers and needs to take these three as parameters. Else `c` is not defined in `actual_func`.

Complete code:

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def addition(a,b):
        c = a*b
        return func(a,b,c)
    return addition

@my_decorator
def actual_func(a,b,c):
    return a+b+c
```